# Mysql Order by is not working with the value from if clause

Tags: mysql

I have the sql query with if condition and order by the if condition value, but order by is not working properly. And I have all my value column (creditamt,debitamt) in decimal data type.

Here is my code

```
 select batchno,fperiod,date,reference,desp,"7.00" as taxpec,sequal,
 if(creditamt-debitamt='0.00','0.00',((creditamt-debitamt)*-1)) as kdebitamt
 from glpost where rem4='SR'and reference="INV-A00428"
 and (fperiod between '1' and '11' AND gstperiod=0) 
 order by kdebitamt;
```

The outcome is

> 14.53
>   2467.94
>   270.00
>   3000.00

Expected Result is

> 14.53
>   270.00
>   2467.97
>   3000.00

Hope that somebody can help me out. Thanks for your help.

**Edit : The Original Data Form**
[image]
both of the debitamt, creditamt data types are decimal(10,2)

Comment: What is the data type for kdebitamt? does order by cast(kdebitamt as decimal) work for you

Comment: the kdebitamt is the alias, and is from the decimal datatype of creditamt. I have tried the cast() and the trick kdebitamt+0, both did'nt work

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. That includes input. It would also be helpful if you selected the columns in question.

Comment: Please use text (in code format when it's a table), [not images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097), for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ordering by a string column; use the numeric column instead

```
select batchno,fperiod,date,reference,desp,"7.00" as taxpec,sequal,
if(creditamt-debitamt='0.00','0.00',(creditamt-debitamt)*-1 ) as kdebitamt
from glpost where rem4='SR'and reference="INV-A00428"
and (fperiod between '1' and '11' AND gstperiod=0) 
order by (creditamt-debitamt)*-1;
```

Note, when the column alias kdebitamt is used by the ORDER BY clause, you have used strings `'0.00'` forcing it to treat that column (if referenced by that alias) as a string column. However the source column is numeric, so just refer to the source column name, not the alias.

alternative, use this instead and kdebitamt is then numeric:

```
if(creditamt-debitamt=0,0,(creditamt-debitamt)*-1 ) as kdebitamt
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed something out within the if clause, suppose is if not equal to zero, (creditamt-debitamt)*-1 instead of creditamt. May I ask that how to let the alias be treated as numeric value?

Comment: amended answer for that change in the IF()

Comment: Thank you very much, I really missed out the "0.00". It works great after all